# Iterate through upper triangle of NxN matrix in specific order

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

I have NxN matrix of zeros. I want to write data stored in std::vector to upper-right triangle (including diagonal) of this matrix. My problem is that I need to write the data to it in specific order: let my source data vector is `data` and matrix we're writing to is `mtr` and its size is for example 5x5.

So `data[0]` should be written to `mtr[0][4]` (upper right vertex).

`data[1]` - `mtr[0][3]` ; `data[2]` - `mtr[1][4]` (second "row" of triangle).

`data[3]` - `mtr[0][2]` ; `data[4]` - `mtr[1][3]` ; `data[5]` - `mtr[2][4]` (third "row" of triangle). And so on. As you can see from example - I need to write data to this triangle sequentially, line by line.

I just can't think of a suitable loop.

Comment: To solve a problem, it is necessary to describe it clearly (unless you rely on blind luck),    You haven't described your problem clearly enough for YOU to solve it, let alone for anyone else to be able to help you.  Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @Peter what exactly is unclear there? I think the decsription is quite clear and easy to understand. What should I add to description so you can understand it better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
int data_index = 0;
for (int diagonal = N-1; diagonal >= 0; --diagonal) {
    for (int i = 0; i + diagonal < N; ++i) {
        mtr[i][i+diagonal] = data[data_index];
        ++data_index;
    }
}
```

Just make sure that `diagonal` is signed (`int` in this example), or use its complement to `N-1` and change the decrementation into an incrementation.

Or you could create an iterator for your matrix using a similar idea. Here is a crude example (a correct iterator would be more complete and so more complex):

```
template<int N>
class Matrix<N>::DiagonalIterator {
    Matrix<N>& m;
    int row;
    int column;
public:
    using difference_type = int;
    using value_type = int;
    using pointer = int*;
    using reference = int&;
    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;

    DiagonalIterator(Matrix<N>& m, int row, int column)
    : m(m), row(row), column(column) {
    }

    auto operator*() -> int& {
        return m.inner[row*N + column];
    }

    auto operator++() -> Matrix<N>::DiagonalIterator& {
        if (row == N-1) {
            row = N-column;
            column = 0;
        } else if (column == N-1) {
            column = N-2-row;
            row = 0;
        } else {
            ++row;
            ++column;
        }

        return *this;
    }
};
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59f4331387ec89a2)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It suits me almost perfectly. But I should add that in second for loop we need also check `data_index < data.size()`. Because if we won't do this, we will be getting `out of range` errors in data[data_index] every time when we can't fill one of triangle rows completely with data.

Comment: If `data` doesn't necessarily contain enough elements, then of course you need to check for the upper bound. Reading your question, I thought that `data` had precisely the same amount of elements as there are in the triangle of the matrix. I added an example of an iterator, which may be too complicated for your case, but brings the advantage of the standard algorithms (in particular, `std::copy`).